# Which one is better Lazy Loading Module or Preload Modules Strategy?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm newbie in angular. Please pardon me if it looks silly question to you.

I'm working on one of angular project and confused how can I decide weather module would be
"Lazy-load module " or "Preload Module".

As per my understanding:

**Lazy-load modules:** It loads module as needed. Lazy loading helps keep initial bundle sizes smaller, which in turn helps decrease load times.

**Preload Modules:** It preloads all modules as quickly as possible.

**Questions:**

1. Which strategy is more efficient in terms of performance.
2. What is the actual use case of preload modules. If possible, please help with an example.

Thanks,

Comment: As per your use-case of project load common task of your project in default `app.module` and load all sub-task of related in feature `lazy loaded module`. for example your project have UseModule, ProductModule, PurchaseModule all are lazyLoaded module when user needs it they will load as per requirement. DashBoard of project is your default root app.module , in which all lazy loaded module loaded by user as per their requirements

Answer (score 0):

Generally lazy loaded modules are considered a best practice.  It reduces your initial load time since it will only load the modules relevant to the route that you are on.

It is somewhat dependent on your application though.  If you have a small application it probably won't matter much.  If your users are going to visit every part of your application every time you visit then it won't buy you much either.  It will just spread out the load times.  If you're developing an app for an intranet or some other situation where bandwidth isn't much of an issue then lazy loading modules isn't as important either.